# Android Bluetooth discoverable time is always 120 seconds

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-10.0

According to this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#java%20) if you set the EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION extra's value to 0, the device is always discoverable.

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);    
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

but my phone always shoes :

> an app want to enable bluetooth and make your device visible to other device for 120 seconds.

and even if I use another number he still 120 and not only 0 ,exemple : 100,300 ...

I see that problem with lot of people in stackoverflow but always without answers , please someone can help !